# How to bind value to a directive onclick in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am trying to create a bookmark directive which allows the users to click on bookmark icon for first time and color will change to blue along with value 1 and will not be allowed to click again.
On click of bookmark icon,the default color(black) should change to blue, also the directive should be bind with value 1.Default value will  be zero.
Currently I am unable to set the value to  zero(default) nor onclick set to 1 but the color changes.

Here is my code:

```js
var a=angular.module('Rating', []);
  a.controller('RatingCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
       bookmark: false
     };
    
    $scope.saveBookmark=function(value){
     
      
    }
  });
  
 a.directive('buttonBookmark', function() {
   return {
      scope: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      bookVal: '=',
      onBookSelected : '&',
      template: '<span style="font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;" ng-model="myModal"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" ng-class="{active: item.bookmark}"></span>',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        elem.bind('click', function() {
           
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.item.bookmark = !scope.item.bookmark;
              
          });
        });
          
          scope.toggle = function(index) {
            
      scope.bookVal = index + 1;
      scope.onBookSelected({
       value : index + 1
      });
     };
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
  .glyphicon-bookmark {
    color: black !important;
    
  }
  
  .active{
  
  color:royalblue !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='Rating' ng-controller="RatingCtrl"> 
  <span style="font-size: 12px !important;">Bookmark</span>
          <button-bookmark book-val='value' on-book-selected='saveBookmark(value)'></button-bookmark>
        
          </body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is `directive should bind with the value 1`

Comment: In  <button-bookmark book-val='value' on-book-selected='saveBookmark(value)'></button-bookmark>
book-val='value', $scope.value should have the value 1 once the user click on the bookmark icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF` condition will prevent it from further clicks.

```js
var app = angular.module('Rating', []);
app.controller('RatingCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    bookmark: false
  };

  $scope.saveBookmark = function(value) {


  }
});

app.directive('buttonBookmark', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    bookVal: '=',
    onBookSelected: '&',
    template: '<span style="font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;" ng-model="myModal"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" ng-class="{active: item.bookmark}"></span>',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {

        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (!scope.item.bookmark) {
            scope.item.bookmark = !scope.item.bookmark;
            scope.value = 1;
          }
        });
      });

      scope.toggle = function(index) {

        scope.bookVal = index + 1;
        scope.onBookSelected({
          value: index + 1
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-bookmark {
  color: black !important;
}
.active {
  color: royalblue !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='Rating' ng-controller="RatingCtrl">
  <span style="font-size: 12px !important;">Bookmark</span>
  <button-bookmark book-val='value' on-book-selected='saveBookmark(value)'></button-bookmark>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks,the solution doesnt allow the user to click again.
Is there any way I can check the style class of bookmark icon on click.
If i click on the icon how can I get the style class as blue color in alert pop up.

Comment: please be clear. Whether you want to click it again and change color OR click once and stop changing color

Comment: User need to click on the icon,the color should change and the user should be restricted from further click.
When the user click on the icon for the first time,'value'(ng-bind) of the directive should bind to 1 so that i can set the value to a $scope in the controller to use it further.
<button-bookmark book-val='value' on-book-selected='saveBookmark(value)'></button-bookmark>

Comment: @ArunAbraham I have given above, the click is prevented when it is not first time and changed the color on first time. The `$scope.value` is also set to 1.